# Tinymce.get and tinymce.activeEditor both return null

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I have a tinymce textarea 
in HTML:
`<textarea id="customer_notes"></textarea>`

And in JS I try to access this textarea with

`tinymce.get('customer_notes').on("keyup", function(){
    console.log("tiny");
})`

OR

`tinymce.activeEditor.on('keyup', function(){
    console.log("keyup");
})`

However, both are returning null. I understand that there can be an issue with the element not being loaded on the page yet, and therefore is inaccessible.

BUT just above either statement I try, if I output `console.log(tinymce.editors);` it outputs an array containing my textarea, with the id "customer_notes".

`0: {…}, id: "customer_notes", isNotDirty: true, plugins: {…}, …}ustomer_notes: eN { id: "customer_notes", isNotDirty: true, plugins: {…}, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`

I have read several other posts with this issue, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. One answer suggested using `tinymce.editors[0]` but that is undefined?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine.  If you can share all your HTML and JS then maybe we can pinpoint where the issue is.  In the meantime, here's a working example to hopefully help you along: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaosquare/q9b2gznx/10/).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="customer_notes"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });

  tinymce.get('customer_notes').on("keyup", function(){
    console.log("tiny");
  });

  tinymce.activeEditor.on('keyup', function(){
    console.log("keyup");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture events regarding an instance of TinyMCE you can actually setup these event functions directly in your `init({})` function.

Here is an example:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/7Hgaab

You will see there is a `setup` function in the init and that setup function automatically gets access to your `editor` object so you can setup your `keyup` event function in that `setup` function.

The code to look at in the `init({})` is:

```
setup: function (editor) {
  editor.on('keyup', function (e) {
    console.log('A key was pressed: ', e.keyCode); 
  });
}
```